# Asp.net core middleware to run logic based on request url

Tags: asp.net-core, microservices

I have an .net core application that works as api gateway and authentication service at the same time. The authentication controller looks like this:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost, Route("request")]
    public IActionResult RequestToken([FromBody] TokenRequest request)
    {

        string token = "";
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }


        if (_authService.IsAuthenticated(request, out token))
        {
            return Ok(token);
        }

        return BadRequest("Invalid Request");
    }
```

Is there a way to crate a middleware that can distinguish the request url so I can redirect it to the controller when it is smth like "/auth" and "OTHERS". The "OTHERS" should be redirected to a service, which works running the following in Configure method:

```
app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
                {
                    var routing = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IRoutingService>();

                    var content = await routing.RouteRequest(context.Request);
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(await content.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                    content.Dispose();

                    // Seed the database.
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a middleware for "others" requests and then map to it using [Map](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.mapextensions.map?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DDE-DE%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.MapExtensions.Map);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=aspnetcore-2.2) method:

- So you have an interface and an implementation, e.g:

```
    public interface IRoutingService
    {
        Task<HttpResponseMessage> RouteRequest(HttpRequest request);
    }

    public sealed class RoutingService : IRoutingService
    {
        public Task<HttpResponseMessage> RouteRequest(HttpRequest request)
        {
            // your code    
        }
    }
```

- Add it to services:

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddTransient<IRoutingService, RoutingService>();
        }
    }
```

- Define a middleware using dependency injection in constructor for `IRoutingService` type:

```
    public static class OthersExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseOthers(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<OthersMiddleware>();
        }
    }

    public sealed class OthersMiddleware
    {
        private readonly IRoutingService routing;

        public OthersMiddleware(RequestDelegate _, IRoutingService routing) => this.routing = routing;

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            var content = await routing.RouteRequest(context.Request);

            await context.Response.WriteAsync(await content.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

            content.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

- Use it:

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.Map("/others", builder => builder.UseOthers());
        }
    }
```

- And for the authentication controller just specify the route using [RouteAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.routeattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.2):

```
    [Route("auth")]
    public class AuthenticationController
    {
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This seems to be working fine. But how I make the decision between going to the routing services or the auth controllers? I mean is there a way to know the incoming URL? What I want to achieve is : IF (AUTH) { GO TO CONTROLLER  ACTION AUTH } ELSE { USE "others" MIDDLEWHERE }

Comment: @Flezcano you do not need to make the decision. Just specify the route for the authentication controller.